# How to set up shaderVertex and shader fragment in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

Actually, I want to create a shader fragment and a shader vertex.But what are the extension of both of the two files ? I try "fragment.glsl" But the fragment is not compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual extensions are `.vs` or `.vertex` for vertex shaders `.fs` or `.fragment` for fragment shaders. There's also `.gs` for geometry shaders, if supported by your target platform/device.  The OpenGL Shader Builder seems to use them interchangeably.

- [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS: Best Practices for Shaders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW3)